# What does this error mean - "Instance of Num Char required for definition of versioncheck"?

Tags: haskell

```
versioncheck::String -> String -> Bool
versioncheck [] [] = True

versioncheck (x:xs) [] 
    |x /= 0 = False
    |otherwise = versioncheck xs [] 

versioncheck (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | x /= y = False
  | otherwise = versioncheck xs ys
```

Why to I get the error - "Instance of Num Char required for definition of versioncheck"?

Comment: Because you compare `Char` with something numeric in line `|x /= 0 = False`.

Comment: In particular, `String` means `[Char]`, so `x :: Char`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach to solving this kind of problem—and one that I can recommend—is to feed your function definition to the compiler *without the accompanying type signature* and then use the interactive environment to inspect the type that the compiler inferred for the function.

In your case, if we define

```
versioncheck []     []     = True
versioncheck (x:xs) [] 
  |x /= 0                  = False
  |otherwise               = versioncheck xs [] 
versioncheck (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | x /= y                 = False
  | otherwise              = versioncheck xs ys
```

and then, in GHCi, query

```
> :type versioncheck
```

it gives us

```
versioncheck :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

making explicit that your function operates on two lists with elements drawn from the same type `a` and that this type `a` should be in both the class `Eq` of types that have values that can be tested for equality and the class `Num` of numeric types.

Where do these class constraints come from? The first (for `Eq`) is introduced by you comparing elements of the two input lists with `/=`. The second (for `Num`) by you comparing  an element of the first list with a numeric value (`0`).

Now, the type signature that you provided reads `String -> String -> Bool`. As strings are just lists of characters, this expands into `[Char] -> [Char] -> Bool`. Comparing this to the inferred signature, your signature instantiates the type variable `a` with `Char`. As far as the `Eq`-constraint on `a` is concerned this is okay as `Char` is indeed an instance of `Eq`. However, `Char` is not, as required, an instance of `Num` (and so the compiler cannot know how to perform the test `x /= 0`); hence, the type error.

One resolution would be to go with the inferred signature, but if it is really lists of characters that you want to process, you will have to get rid of the test `x /= 0` and compare `x` with a character value. For example:

```
versioncheck :: String -> String -> Bool
versioncheck []     []     = True
versioncheck (x:xs) []
  |x /= '0'                = False
  |otherwise               = versioncheck xs []
versioncheck (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x /= y                 = False
  | otherwise              = versioncheck xs ys
```

(note the quotes in `'0'`) compiles just fine.

Comment: I guess it's just a typo, but you're comparing to the '0' character and not the '\0' character

Comment: danvari: I have no idea about the intended semantics of the OP's function. Hence, I cannot really tell what makes a sensible check. In any case: no typo, just speculation.